# Missing pictures when using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When preparing an article I came across with a strange problem. To draw graphs I use pgfplots.

Like here:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{daiostyle}

\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\asbuk{subfigure}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!hb]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.85]
        \begin{axis}[xmax=105, xmin=0, ymax=120, ymin=0, ylabel=\small{y}, xlabel=\small{x}, grid=major]
            \addplot[blue, mark=none] table{PlowMenExp1L.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A caption}\label{PlowMenExp1L}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Package daiostyle can be found [here](http://www.math.nsc.ru/publishing/DAOR/Daionewstyle.zip)

Dat file [here](http://pastebin.com/cA617cmn)

But what I get looks like this one:

[image: output]

I don't understand, what is wrong. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I added the image for you.

Comment: Did you try only with ascii characters on the captions?

Comment: The non-ASCII characters don't seem to be problematic...

Comment: The problem is not with characters. Cause when I remove all captions and labels, the situation doesn't change - I get nothing, no graph, but should be like this: http://clip2net.com/s/5uBGCe

Comment: Updated an issue.

Comment: Which route are you compiling `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or direct `pdflatex` ? `daiostyle.sty` contains dvips driver while including graphics `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` hence `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` route is required. make sure compiling steps and drivers match or else comment the lines. see [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yjI3A.png) if it is what you need

Comment: I have no idea what \usepackage{daiostyle} does, nor could I find it. But removing it worked fine on your code when I tried it.

Comment: @JohnKotmylo The `daiostyle` package is linked to in the question.

Comment: @texenthusiast thanks! I used pdflatex only, but according to your advice I tried latex-dvi-pdf and it worked =) Some problems concerning not very good alignment of subfigures in a square, but that's not the case =) Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Comment made into Answer as it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Comment made into Answer as it worked for OP.

`daiostyle.sty` contains `dvips` driver while including graphics `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` hence `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` route is required.

Always make sure compiling route and driver options match each other or else comment those lines. With `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` the output is as shown below

[image]